# Is it okay to use Angular *ngFor to repeat static content

Tags: angular, ngfor

I want to create 6 `<a>` tags with different background colors and images in it. All the colors and images are static data. Should I hardcode all the `<a>` tags or use `*ngFor` for the same with an array? Is there any performance difference between them?

Comment: Personally I would use the ngFor, not sure about the performance tho. Anyway, imagine your static content receives a change. If you define all 6 elements, then you need to do the same change 6 times. In case of ngFor you only change it once.

Comment: you have not a large data set, just 6 items, so there is not difference but using ngfor is more readable.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm I also would like to do the same. But I am really curious to know about the difference.

Comment: you can still define 6 elements without *ngFor, bind their variables that will change, and handle changes for all 6 in them without code duplication.

Comment: To reduce code duplication you could also use a ng-template and pass the variables to it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If that content is really static I'd prefer hardcoding it into the web page instead of using `ngFor`. Moreover, you say that all of links are different, it means you will need to pass a lot of data into the array of items (styles or classnames, titles, hrefs, etc). So, it is much faster to just code them once with HTML.

From the performance perspective it is also better. In your case, if you use `ngFor` you make angular to run internal things without real reason to do that. Also you actually create unnecessary binding to the local variable (array of items).

I think in this particular case, it is easier and faster just use HTML.

Note: By *static content* I consider content which is not going to be changed in any way during all the time user interacts with the application.

Answer (score 0):

The performance impact you get with such a small, immutable data set is insignificant. In my opinion the better readability and maintainability of using `ngFor` is more important.

An alternative to `ngFor` while keeping the same benefits are `NgTemplateOutlets`. You can read more on this here: https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet

Comment: Can not agree about readability, because 6 lines of HTML code are much readable then array of 6 objects with at least 3 fields in each of them.